# Determining if polyline has true curve using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.7, true-curves, densify

I'm using ArcPy with ArcMap 10.7.1.

I want to densify SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polylines **if (and only if)** the polylines have true curves.

If I were using ArcPy with the latest version of ArcGIS Pro (instead of ArcMap), then I think the [hasCurves](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm#:%7E:text=Point-,hasCurves,-(Read%20Only)) property could be used:

```
for row in cursor:
    polyline = row[0]
    if polyline.hasCurves() == True:
        polyline = polyline.densify('ANGLE', 10, 0.174533) #radians
```

Unfortunately, the `hasCurves` property doesn't seem to be available for a [Polyline](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm) in ArcMap 10.7.1.

```
#ArcPy/ArcMap 10.7.1

AttributeError: 'Polyline' object has no attribute 'hasCurves'
```

In ArcMap 10.7.1, is there an alternative option for determining if polylines have true curves?

Comment: If you get extra vertices on the straight parts I think you can get rid of them by simplifying with a small tolerance.

Comment: @user30184 Good idea! In my case, these sewer lines have other lines that are snapped to existing mid-line vertices. Example: a house sewer connection is snapped to a vertex within the sewer main line (not snapped to an endpoint of the line). So I need to be careful with simplifying lines. I don't want to compromise the topological integrity (lots if manual work went into it).

Comment: Have you considered to make a sort of topological backup by saving the connections also as a separate point layer?

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any guarantees about preserving topology, but I will say that I've used the WKT trick before with success.  IIRC, it looked something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for geom, in cursor:
        geom = arcpy.FromWKT(geom.WKT)
        cursor.updateRow([geom])
```

**This will modify your data in-place**, so make sure to have a backup.

Comment: Thanks! For our notes, here are the docs for the [FromWKT function](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-functions/fromwkt.htm) for ArcMap 10.7.1

Comment: Regarding your comment about *modifying data in-place"*. Do you have any techniques you use for testing? What I've been doing is: in a test FC, I have features that serve as the *master* features. I flag them as MASTER in a field. Then, before each test, in ArcMap, I copy/paste them, and flag them as something other than MASTER. In my ArcPy script, I have a line that tells the script to ignore any features that are flagged as MASTER. ... That way, I can do my testing, and modify the data in place. But I won't need to re-create my data for each test (or if something goes wrong).

Comment: Normally I'd just stick a `CopyFeatures_management()` in front of the `UpdateCursor`, or create a new empty feature class and use a `SearchCursor` + an `InsertCursor`

Comment: I'd like to add that the WKT technique seems to return identical results as using `Geometry.densify("ANGLE", infinity, 2*pi/202)`, at least for circular arcs, not bezier curves though.  Not sure which is faster.

Comment: I guess those arguments only give identical results for circular polygons, WKT method must be a more fancy algorithm because it's not quite the same for other curves.  In any case, densifying to a 1 degree max angular deviation seems to be around 4x faster than working with the WKT.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that, in my case, I might not actually need to check if a polyline has true curves or not.

My scenario is: I only want to densify segments that are true curves. But I think I can do that by applying densify() to **all** lines (with curve(s) or not). The trick to *not* densifying lines without curves (or straight segments *within* lines with curves) might just be to use densify() ***properly***.

> [densify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm#:%7E:text=The%20type%20of%20densification) (type, distance, deviation)
>
> - TYPE: ANGLE
> - DISTANCE: a really big number that would never happen, like 10,000 metres.
>
>   - Is there a reason this argument isn't optional?
> - Deviation: 0.174533 radians (10 degrees)

```
polyline.densify ("ANGLE", 10000, 0.174533)
```

---

I'm not 100% sure if that actually *is* the proper way to use densify() for true curves. Would welcome corrections.